# How to assign a function to a object method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to 'proxy' (not sure if that's the term at all) a function inside a function object for easy calling.

Given the following code

```
function Soldier() {
    this.el = $("<div></div>").addClass('soldier');
    this.pos = this.el.position; // $(".soldier").position(), or so I thought
}
```

In the console:

```
s = new Soldier();
$("#gamemap").append(s.el); // Add the soldier to the game field
s.pos === s.el.position // this returns true
s.el.position() // Returns Object {top: 0, left: 0}
s.pos() // Returns 'undefined'
```

What am I doing wrong in this scenario and is there an easy way to achieve my goal (`s.pos()` to return the result of `s.el.position()`) ?
I thought about `s.pos = function() { return s.el.position(); }` but looks a bit ugly and not apropriate. Also I'd like to add more similar functions and the library will become quite big to even load.

Comment: I think you have to bind `this` to your method explicitly. JavaScript is quirky in how it deals with that variable: `s.pos = this.el.position.bind(this.el)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling `s.pos()`, its `this` context is lost.
You can simulate this behavior using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
s.pos.call(s); // same as s.pos()
s.pos.call(s.el); // same as s.el.position()
```

This code is actually ok:

```
s.pos = function() { return s.el.position(); }
```

An alternative is using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
s.pos = s.el.position.bind(el);
```

You can use the prototype, that way the functions will not be created separately for every object:

```
Soldier.prototype.pos = function(){ return this.el.position(); }
```

Comment: Thank you! Accepted answer due to being most extensive,  easy to understand explanation and link to docs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use the prototype:

```
Soldier.prototype.pos = function() { return this.el.position(); };
```

Not ugly at all, and quite performant actually.

If you want to directly assign it in the constructor, you'll need to notice that the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) of a `s.pos()` invocation would be wrong. You therefore would need to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it:

```
    …
    this.pos = this.el.position.bind(this.el);
```

Comment: Thanks, upvote for the performant solution as well as doc links.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the context of execution for `position` method has changed. If you bind the method to work inside the element context it will work.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fut8hy3L/2/)

```
function Soldier() {
    this.el = $("<div></div>").addClass('soldier');
    this.pos = this.el.position.bind(this.el); 
}

var s = new Soldier();
$("#gamemap").append(s.el); 
console.log(s.pos());
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote for fiddle, working code and explanation of the problem.